# How to uninstall / re-install a Magento extension and preserve associated database data

Tags: magento-1.9

I already installed an extension on my live site. The extension has a lot of associated data stored in database tables. Due to problems with the extension, I plan to uninstall and re-install it again.

How can ensure that I do not lose the database data associated with my extension?

Comment: Did you install that extension via Magento Connect or somehow else?

Comment: No i install that extension through files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to reinstall extension code but leave its database tables not touched, just overwrite extension code with original code from extension package. As you don't touch `core_resource` table, database installer scripts shouldn't run again so data won't be changed or removed.

In case you want to recreate all database tables and data installed by extension you will need to review extension code in its `data/` and `sql/` directories and do these manually:

- remove all tables created bye extension
- manually undo all changes done in existing Magento tables (eg. fields or indexes added to Magento core tables)
- remove all data added by extension to database (eg. product attributes)
- remove extension entry from `core_resource` table

Answer (score 2):

**Create a backup** your current database, and the current database table(s) belonging to your extension before you uninstall and reinstall the extension. The database backup helps you to recover the whole shop, the extension tables if you want to transform/import certain data later (as mentioned in your question).

There will **sql install/upgrade scripts**  and **data install/upgrade scripts** that create your database tables and content during extension installation which will throw an error, if the table(s) are already existing.
Check your `/sql` and `/data` folder of the extension and delete those tables manually first (after the backup ;-) ).